# Direct proof that pointed protomodularity implies the Mal'cev property

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

It is a theorem that a finitely complete protomodular category is Mal'cev. The proof in the Bourn-Borceux monograph relies on classification via the fibration of points.

Is there perhaps a more direct proof in the pointed case? That is, how can one prove directly that pointed protomodularity implies every reflexive relation is an equivalence relation? I don't see how to use protomodularity to obtain symmetry and transitivity arrows for a given reflexive relation.

The obvious proof for groups relies on using inverses and I don't see how to generalize it to the pointed-protomodular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a direct proof valid in any category with finite limits. It is given as Theorem 5.9 (pages 16-17) in [these notes](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~tholen/HB07BournClementino.pdf), and as Theorem 3.18 in Chapter IV of the book [Categorical Foundations](https://books.google.be/books?id=WHudOFwuMn8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=categorical%20foundations&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCsc-R0OjVAhUOfFAKHTUbBIoQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=categorical%20foundations&f=false).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is very different from the proof in Borceux-Bourn (I don't have access to the book right now), so sorry if this turns out to be useless. I think that I have another proof for homological categories in some (handwritten) notes of a course I followed during my Master degree, but I need some time to reorganize it that I don't have right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references. I will take a look at the proofs in the upcoming days. Just out of curiosity - was the course you followed taught by an active researcher in categorical algebra? It was my impression that generic courses touching on category theory do not delve into protomodularity and categorical algebra in general.

Comment: Yes, it was taught by a researcher in categorical algebra. It was an advanced course on special topics in category theory for PhD and master students interested in doing research. Categorical algebra is one of the main area of research in my institution.

Comment: Regarding the proof of theorem 3.18 in chapter IV of 'Categorical Foundations': In the final paragraph, how does Proposition 3.9(3) imply $j$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Proposition 3.9(3) imply that $i_0$ and $i_1$ are jointly strongly epimorphic (because the squares induced by the sections are also pullbacks), or equivalently jointly extremally epimorphic; since they both factor by $j$, $j$ must be an iso.

Comment: Sorry for bugging you yet again, but I don't see which split pullback square involves both $i_0,i_1$, so I don't see where to apply 3.9(3). What are the pullback squares induced by the sections? Simply the triangles $j∘s_k=i_k$? I'm not following..

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than I thought, because the sections are not always those I expected. But if I'm not mistaken, the square $\pi_0\circ i_1 =s_0\circ d_0$ (it's not actually written, but it should commute) is a pullback, and then you can use the fact that $\pi_0 i_0=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Zurab Janelidze has done quite a bit of work on characterizing categories via the properties of their internal relations. In particular he characterizes pointed protomodular categories via their internal relations in the paper *[Closedness Properties of Internal Relations III: Pointed Protomodular Categories](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-007-9072-9)*, which then trivially implies that pointed protomodular categories are Mal'cev when you use the characterization of Mal'cev categories via their relations (as he does in the paper). Whether you find this is more or less direct than Bourn's proof will I guess depend on whether you're willing to take Janelidze's relational approach as more basic than the fibrational approach of Bourn.